# How to use AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS and separate build and source directories?

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I am using autotools to build a large project. I can use AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS and SUBDIRS to have a master project configure and build subprojects. I can also separate the object files from the source by building a subproject in a separate build directory. What I cannot fathom is how to do both - that is to get the master project to build the subprojects in a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the subdirectories passed to AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS really must be subdirectories. I was passing things like ../cfi since the master project was beside rather than above the subordinate projects.

Some judicious soft-links and it all compiles fine.

I hope this is useful to anyone else that stumbles down this path.

Comment: Do you have a link to any references on why this might be the case?